# Get last N records in a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way to get the last N records from a dynamodb table. The range key I have is the timestamp. So I could use the ScanIndex forward to order items chronologically.

But in order to query I need to have a hashKey condition, which I don't want to filter. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

DynamoDB is not designed to work this way. The items are distributed according to a hash on the HashKey in such a way that the order is not predictable.

Your options include:

- grouping the items under a single hash key (not recommended: you would overload a few servers with your data, and Amazon cannot guarantee your read/write capacity)
- scanning the whole table and keep the N most recent items (something like `for (item in items) { if (item newer then oldest accumulated item) accumulate item; }`);
- partition your table into multiple tables (ie, instead of a table called `Events`, create one called `Events20130705` for today's events, `Events20130706` for tomorrow's events), and scan just like the previous option -- this way your scans are smaller

You could also maybe change your data model. For example, You could have one *versioned* entry that would keep references to the N most recent items. Or you could have something like a single counter that you'd increment and update N other entries under hashkeys such as *recent-K* where K is your counter mod N.

Maybe you could even use another tool for this job. For instance, you could have a Redis server to do this. Without knowing your use case with much more detail, it is hard to make a precise suggestion -- how scalable should this be? how reliable should it be? how much maintenance are you willing to perform? how much are you willing to pay for it?

It's usually better to embrace the limitation, know your constraints and be creative.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about this, but worth a shot asking!

Comment: Looks like this answer, from 2013, just got a downvote. Any specific reasons? I reread it in the context of the question, and it seems still applicable (basically the only difference would be that, 2.5 years later, in Dec. 2015 DynamoDB renamed Hash and Range to Partition and Sort keys, but they are conceptually equivalent and kept their original names in the API)

Comment: @BrunoReis: Maybe someone didn't like your answer that it's not just working the easy way - like me :-). Interesting alternatives. I am thinking about alternative one (single hash key) and keep the table small by shifting out older entries from time to time. I want to hold some entities for a chat and only need the last maybe 100 entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is still relevant. I'm fairly sure you can use ScanIndexForward along with a rangeKey to get the latest value.

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately :(
The reason being that ScanIndexForward is a parameter of the Query API, which requires you to set an EQ comparison on a HashKey, which is exactly what the OP wants to avoid. This means that the OP would need to know the most recent Hash Key used in advance (then the problem becomes trivial, but very unlikely to be a real-world problem), or would need to do something like the first bullet point in my answer above, which is still (2.5 years later) considered a bad practice.